# Can't figure out Javascript Countdown

Tags: javascript

I need help making a Countdown timer!

The user types a value into a text field, the timer starts when a button is clicked.

The timer text decreases by one every second until it reaches zero.

I have code for the first step, but can't seem to get the second step to work. I know it needs to include a setTimeout and loop.

Heres the code so far :

HTML-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


</head>
<body>



<div id="form">

<h2> COUNTDOWN</h2>

    Seconds: <input type="text" name="seconds" id="seconds" /> <input type="button" value="Start!" id="start" /> <input type="button" value="Pause" id="pause"  />
</div>


<div id="info">


</div>


<div id="countdown">


</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT-

```
window.onload = function(){

var startButton = document.getElementById("start");

var form = document.getElementById("seconds");

var pause = document.getElementById("pause");

var secDiv = document.getElementById("countdown");

var editSec = document.createElement("h1");


startButton.onclick = function (){

editSec.innerHTML = form.value;
secDiv.appendChild(editSec);


};


};
```

Comment: You can look at my source code for my multiple countdown time site PlentyOfTime if you would like: http://derek.genevievehoward.com/projects/4/index.php

Comment: I don't know if it is crucial, but you are including your .js file after calling the editSec

Comment: You actually have two body elements, which is not valid!

Comment: Click on the checkmark beside the correct answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes:

```
var globalTime = form.value; //receive the timer from the form
var secDiv = document.getElementById("countdown");

function decreaseValue() {
  globalTime = globalTime - 1;

   secDiv.innerHTML = globalTime;
}

startButton.onclick = function (){
  setTimeout(decreasValue(),1000);
};

//clear out the timers once completed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setInterval, not setTimeout. Add this code to the onclick function:

```
editSec.id = "editSec";
window.cdint = setInterval(function(){ 
    var origVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("editSec").innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("editSec").innerHTML = origVal - 1;
    if(origVal - 1 <= 0){
        window.cdint = clearInterval(window.cdint);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
var time = 100;
var countdown = function(){
    secdiv.innerHTML = time;
    time--;
}
setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` if you want :

```
startButton.onclick = function () {
    var value = parseInt(form.value);
    editSec.innerHTML = value;
    secDiv.appendChild(editSec);
    setTimeout(function () {
        editSec.innerHTML = --value < 10
            ? '<span style="color:red">' + value + '</span>'
            : value;
        if (value) {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: if I wanted to now add a if statement to make the numbers smaller than 10 change to red, where would I add it in?